# Insert Image into Office Word Online from external web app

Tags: javascript, ms-office, office-js

I am developing an add-in app for Office Word Online. Have created a add-in with manifest which will redirect users to our web application, then the user selects an image from their account(within our web app). On this selection I need to add the selected image to their document.

The clarification is whether I need to use the [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview) or the [Word Javascript API](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/javascript-api-for-office)

1. Can Microsoft Graph API used to insert image to a document? The documentation or sample will be helpful.
2. Can the add-in script(included to a word document) accessed from our web application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Office Add-in development: Insert image/picture in Word 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38179333/office-add-in-development-insert-image-picture-in-word-2016)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do the insertion with MSGraph. (You could use Graph to the the document.) I think you need the Office JS libraries. The sample here does something similar with PowerPoint, but it would work for Word too since it uses the shared part of the Office JS: [PowerPoint-Add-in-Microsoft-Graph-ASPNET-InsertChart](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PowerPoint-Add-in-Microsoft-Graph-ASPNET-InsertChart)