# Office.js Add-in: Insert image/picture in Excel (Office 365)

Tags: javascript, office-js, office-addins

How do you add a simple image to a specific location on an excel spreadsheet using the new Office.js api?

Comment: The new JS APIs don't yet support this feature. It is in the roadmap and coming soon. The 1.0 API needs to be used as shown in below answer.

Comment: Can I request you edit Question Title to be more generic now that you've resolved so this can be a thread for future users. IE: Just remove `2016` as this can apply to `Office 365` which many of us are using. It doesn't appear your question was specific to 2016.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Excel API 1.9 you can use the method

`addImage(base64ImageString: string): Excel.Shape;`

from the worksheet `ShapeCollections`

from the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-shapes#images you can add an image like this

```
    Excel.run(function (context) {
        var myBase64 = "your bas64string here";
        var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("MyWorksheet");
        var image = sheet.shapes.addImage(myBase64);
        image.name = "Image";
        return context.sync();
    }).catch(errorHandlerFunction);
```

this however inserts the shape at the top left position

after Excel 1.10 you can get the `top` and `left` position of a range

if you want to reposition the images you can do the foloowing

```
Excel.run(async (context) => {
    let sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("MyWorksheet");
    let cell = sheet.getRange("D5")
    cell.load('top,left') //pre-load top and left
    let myBase64 = "your bas64string here";
    const shape = sheet.shapes.addImage(myBase64)

    await context.sync()

    shape.incrementLeft(cell.left) // <- left
    shape.incrementTop(cell.top) // <-top
    await context.sync();
})
```

Answer (score 5):

This answer explains how to do this in Word: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38194807/3806701, and similarly, I was able to do it this way Excel:

```
insertImageBase64New() {
  Excel.run(async (ctx) => {

    let sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1");
    let address = "C3";
    let range = sheet.getRange(address);
    range.select();
    await ctx.sync();

    Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(this.getBase64(), {
      coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Image,
      imageLeft: 0,
      imageTop: 0,
      imageWidth: 300,
      imageHeight: 100
    }, function(asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
          console.log("Action failed with error: " + asyncResult.error.message);
        }
    });
  });
}

getBase64() {
    return "return "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEU..."; //put your base64 encoded image here
}
```

Documentation reference: https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/rangefill

Random website I used to encode an image: https://www.browserling.com/tools/image-to-base64

Comment: How do you import this?